# How can I store a zero in string

Tags: c, string

I have a string `char date[16] ;`
I want, that the last two signs are zero. I have tried:

```
 date[14] = '0';
 date[15] = '0';

 date[16] = '\0';
```

But 0 is same what '\0'. How can I reach what I want?

Comment: do you want to store the '0' char or 0 value?

Comment: then your code is working... storing '0' will store the character '0' in the array while '\0' is your ending trail

Comment: But the string is cutted off just before 0.

Comment: Warning: `date[16]` is not part of an array with space for 16 characters. The last element of `char date[16];` is `date[15]` (the 1st element is `date[0]`).

Comment: those characters aren't "sign", they're digits

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Auto-German-to-English?

Comment: If every off-by-one error caused an equal-but-opposite off-by-one error in the payroll system, I think we'd get people to pay a lot more attention...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storing the character `'0'` in a character array is principally correct the way you have tried it, **but** you say you have `char date[16]` so the indexes including the terminating `'\0'` go from 0 to 15, you must not assign anything to `date[16]`.

Depending on what the complete content of `date` is, it should be either `char date[17]` or

```
date[13] = '0';
date[14] = '0';

date[15] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 4):

`'0'` is *not* the same as `'\0'`.

The character `'0'` has the ascii value of `48`.

`'\0'` is an *escaped* value (by the `\`) and refers to the ascii value `0`, which is the null character.

So, `date[14] = '0'` will store the *symbol* `0`, while `date[14]='\0'` will store the *value* `0` (and mark it as the end of a null-terminated string).

Comment: The string is cutted off. It prints only 13 signs.

Comment: C arrays are zero indexed. only getting 13 symbols implies `date[12]` is null.

Comment: @OliverMatthews: if `date[12]` is `'\0'`, `printf("%s", date);` will print up to (and including) 12 characters.

Comment: For completeness: The offical name for the "null" character is `NUL` (with **one** `L`).

Comment: True, but I figured in this case it would (if anything) cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is not fully printed, then maybe there is some garbage `'\0'` in it.
Have you initialized the whole array ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char date[] = { [0 ... 14] = '0', [15] = '\0' };

    printf("%s\n", date);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `000000000000000` as expected.

Comment: This isn't standard C so I wouldn't recommend it. A better solution is `char date[16] = {'\0'}; memset(date, '0', sizeof(date)-1);`.

Comment: in what c dialect is written the code you posted?

Comment: In __ISO C99__ you can give the elements in any order, specifying the array indices or structure field names they apply to, and __GNU C__ allows this as an extension in __C90__ mode as well. Initialize a range of elements to the same value is a __GNU Extension__, but __clang__ supports it as well. [__Source__](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html)

Answer (score 0):

Storing `'0'` character in `date[14] = '0';` will do exactly what you want.

Comment: No. the string is cutted off. It prints only 13 signs.

Comment: can you post the whole code...? looks like another question should be asked

Comment: whoever downvoted - can you explain why? the other answer in this page is exactly as mine...

Comment: I think it is the question author down voting ones which don't solve his problem. Unfortunately, I suspect he has the wrong question.

Comment: @OliverMatthews - i agree - this looks like the case, anyhow just want to understand the background...